# Inserting values inside an array

Tags: php, arrays

Lets say I have this variables:

```
$build_1 = 'bricks, stones and other stuff';

$build_2 = 'more bricks, houses and other things';
```

How can I insert the content of `$build_1` and `$build_2` in a third variable like `$build_total`?

After that, I want to insert `$build_total` inside a mysql database and get 'bricks, stones and other stuff, more bricks, houses and other things'.

Comment: And where is the array you're talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$build_total = $build_1 . ', ' . $build_2;
```

?

Answer (score 1):

```
$build_total = $build1 . ", " . $build2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If $build_1 and $build_2 would be in an array, you could use the [implode](http://php.net/implode)-method.

```
<?php
$build = array("bricks, stones and other stuff", "more bricks, stones and other stuff");
$build_total = implode(", ", $build);
?>
```